# Tigergraph - recreate tuples

Tags: tigergraph, gsql

I need to write a command-line utility which redefines/updates the graph schema.

For doing this I need to:

- drop the graph
- drop existing tuples
- define new tuples
- define a new graph

The problem is in the "drop existing tuples" stage.
I do it by running the following command for all tuple names which I have to recreate:

```
gsql 'DROP TUPLE < tupleName >'
```

This works well for Tigergraph v3.1.2 because `DROP TUPLE MyTuple` drops `MyTuple` if it exists or ignores the statement otherwise.

But for Tigergraph v3.5.1 this strategy doesn't work because it fails if `MyTuple` doesn't exist.

So now I need to run `DROP TUPLE` only for those tuples which were created before.

But the problem is that there is no way to list all tuples (e.g. there is no `Show tuples` command).
And I cannot use `DROP ALL` because I need to update only the specific graph and don't touch everything else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use session parameter `exit_on_error`, like:

```
gsql "set exit_on_error = \"false\"\n
drop tuple mytuple\n
create tuple ...
create graph ...
"
```

You can also use it in a .gsql file.

doc: https://docs.tigergraph.com/tigergraph-server/current/gsql-shell/gsql-sessions#_session_parameters